# Multiple http requests with cancel request

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, https

I'm creating an android app, which needs make some **parallel HTTP/HTTPS requests** (exactly 10).

### **First step**

How can I make this parallel requests in android?

Is it possible to use HTTP and HTTPS at the same time?

**Obs:** Searching in google, I found `ExecutorService`. Can i use this in android? (Does someone have an example?)

### **Second step**

If someone helps with the 1st question, I will have the following scenario:

```
1 request one started   -- (working) --> cloud
2 request two started   -- (working) --> cloud
3 request three started -- (working) --> cloud
```

After some seconds the thread 2 is the 1st one to say 'i finished my work, here is the response of the page', threads 1 and 3 are working.

How can i stop/kill thread 1 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes you can use ExecutorService

   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n);

then use the submit function to execute the task

```
executorService.submit(Runnable task);
```

but there is no guarantee that all of the task will executed at the same time, it's depend on the available resources.

2.
you can shutdown the pool;

```
executorService.shutdown();
```

but There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks.

if you want to use asyncTask notice that :
Starting with HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused by parallel execution.

so the tasks executed on single thread not several threads

Comment: You know if i can combine executor service with assync task?

Comment: @ronniery there is no sense to combine executor service with asynctask.

Comment: So you explaned the question for me, what is the best, async task or executor(Runnable) ( i want build the app for 2.3 until 4.4 android os )?

Comment: The answer is that it depends: AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.) If you need to keep threads running for long periods of time, it is highly recommended you use the various APIs provided by the java.util.concurrent pacakge such as Executor, ThreadPoolExecutor and FutureTask.